# Path between two points in radial topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Hi: I have been asked to find a path between two arbitrary points $p$, $q$ in the context of the radial topology of the plane (A subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is radially open if it contains an open line segment in each direction about each of its points) and I would like to know if this scheme of a proof is correct. I think that the function from [0,1] given by $f(t) = tp + (1-t)q $ is indeed a path since the topology induced over lines by the radial topology is the usual and, as a consequence, the topology induced over any segment of a line is the same than the topology of any real interval. Since $f$ is continuous as a function from $[0,1]$ to any closed real interval, $f$ is continuous and therefore a path.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: sounds correct to me, though I had to guess the definition of "radial topology". If my guess is correct, then any "path" consisting of finitely many straight line segments would indeed be a path in this topology (i.e. could be represented by a continuous function from $[0,1]$).

Comment: @Mirko Sorry, the definition of radial topology is this: A subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is radially open if it contains an open line segment in each direction about each of its points.

Comment: There is some resemblance to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_topology#Path_or_Zeeman_topology see https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1704140

Comment: @Mirko I don't know much about physics nor manifolds, I'm afraid

Comment: Your proof is correct. Rephrasing the proof may give you confidence in your approach. Your main point is that the topology induced over any segment of a line is the same as the topology on the real interval. Thus your path is just the composition of a map from $[0,1]$ to a closed interval and an inclusion.